# AngularJS/HTML(Frontend) and Java RESTful Service(Backend) Hosting

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, web, hosting

I am working on a personal project/website for classifieds from scratch using AngularJS/HTML5 for the frontend and a Java REST Api that will communicate with a database.

My main question is what are some good options to host such a site without costing me a fortune as it is after all just for personal experience and fun.

I have some java background and therefore i would want to focus on a Java based REST service. I am also learning Angular for the frontend.

What would be an ideal hosting solution for my purposes? 
Any thoughts are welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Just a side thought. Why are you using REST API for database? Have considered sites like worldpress?

Comment: I don't want to use sites like wordpress because i want to get involved with the design. I prefer to build it on my own. What are other good options besides a rest api?

Comment: Did you try AWS (Amason Web services ) for hosting. Mate if your application is siple you need not to go for REST webservices. but if you want to expose some of your methods for other application so that they can communicate with your application then web service is an option

Answer (score 1):

Any service that supports Java applications (i.e. Tomcat) and databases should be suffice. AngularJS is client side JavaScript executed on the browser - so hosting plans shouldn't be impacted by this.

Comment: My question is do you know any specific hosting solution i can use that its not too expensive? Will i need 2 different hosting plans? for frontend and another for the rest api (java) ?

Comment: I don't really know about the prices of all the hosting services. You shouldn't need two different hosting plans - the company that hosts your Java application should be able to host your front end web page. (You can have more if you want - to maybe distribute the load).

Comment: @user1472379 Asking for a hosting plan isn't really an on-topic question for StackOverflow. Having said that I think NameCheap would work fine and they have great prices.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need different hosting plan for angular . You can host angular website in tomcat also along with java rest api. Heroku provides free plan along with limitations.